# How can I remove hundreds of users generated by a script?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, users, accounts

I had previously created a bash script that created over 100 users using output from a password generator as usernames. 
So far, the closest solution I have come across is creating a list of users to remove then create a script to run through that list.

I'm curious how someone would get rid of all of those users without having to list all unwanted users manually, or if there is a quick alternative.

Comment: open `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow`, `/etc/group` with your favourite text editor, then delete them.

Comment: and do not remove any ID below 1001.

Comment: Do you want to remove **all** (non-system) users?  Or, are there some users that you want to keep?  If so, do you have a list of them?

Comment: You can probably check `/var/log/auth.log` and find the creation date of all the new users... use awk to make a list of names... and delete those users... depending on how long ago you've created the excess users, and still have the log file.  Search for something like `useradd[3658]: new user: name=`

Comment: @RubberStamp creation date of /home/$USER/ could be another method.

Comment: @Rinzwind: I thought about that too... but depending on how the users were created there may not be a `/home/$USER`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it depends on the command, options you used to add the users and your system configuration. For example, if your system is configured with `UID_MIN` to start from 1000 and there is only one user (your user, with UID 1000) on that system, you could use something like this **to get just the list** of users, in Bash:

```
for user in $(cut -d : -f 1 /etc/passwd)
do
    user_id=$(id -g ${user})
    if [ ${user_id} -ge 1001 -a ${user_id} -le 1100 ]
    then
        echo ${user};
    fi
done
```

You may probably want to also remove the groups and home folders that have been created, if such options have been used during the creation process.

Answer (score 1):

What was posted in the comments really is the simplest solution:

> Open `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow`, `/etc/group` with your favourite text editor, then delete them.

The only thing to add to this, really (which *should* go without saying but doesn't) is: **make a backup of these files before you edit them.**

So you get something like this:

```
sudo cp /etc/passwd /etc/passwd.bak
sudo cp /etc/shadow /etc/shadow.bak
sudo cp /etc/group /etc/group.bak
sudo -e /etc/passwd /etc/shadow /etc/group
```

Now, of course, if you *also* need to delete the home directories of those users, this won't take care of that.  But just to remove the users themselves, this is all you need to do.

---

If you *do* want to remove the home directories, the easiest way is to filter on the difference between the `/etc/passwd` backup and the modified copy:

```
comm -2 -3 /etc/passwd.bak /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f6,6 > /tmp/dirs-to-delete
```

And then (when you are **very** certain that the list contains only what you want) you loop through the list to delete all those files.

I would actually do further sanity checks first, to check for whitespace or other odd conditions:

```
awk 'NF > 1 { printf "Problem with entry <%s> on line %d\n", $0, NR }' /tmp/dirs-to-delete
```

And be sure the directories all actually exist:

```
for d in $(cat /tmp/dirs-to-delete); do
  [ -d "$d" ] ||
    printf 'Supposed directory <%s> is not a directory\n' "$d"
done
```

And be sure there are no characters that will be interpreted as globs (print the line numbers of any lines with special characters):

```
sed -n '/[][*?]/=' /tmp/dirs-to-delete
```

But when I was really satisfied, then:

```
rm -rf $(cat /tmp/dirs-to-delete)
```

(Note that that command is *dangerous as hell* if you don't know *exactly* what is in the file.  You can wipe your hard drive if you're not careful.)

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind explaining a method to remove the home directories?

Comment: @KneeBacquen, updated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how there could possibly be a good way to do this unless you kept track of which users you added (e.g. possibly in a log file, since you generated random user names) or if you had some pattern that you could use to distinguish the users that you want to delete from the users that you want to keep (like maybe all of your "real" usernames only contain alphabetic characters and all of your random usernames contain nonalphabetic characters).

The only thing that I can think that could possibly be time saving is if the set of users you want to keep is either much smaller than the set of users you want to delete, or if they're listed contiguously somewhere. This might actually be the case if you added all the random users at once and then didn't add any other users afterwards. In that situation you might be able to get the list of users like so:

```bsh
cat /etc/passwd | tail -n 100 | cut -d: -f1
```

And then you could also remove them (NOTE: Double-check everything before you run this!):

```bsh
for username in $(cat /etc/passwd | tail -n 100 | cut -d: -f1); do
    sudo userdel "${username}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below line for deleting the users by checking the condition it should not delete the users who have a userid less than `1001`

```
cat /etc/passwd | awk -F ":" '{print $1,$3}' | awk '$2 > 1001 {print “userdel -r”  “ “ $1}’
```